# JavaFX Float Column with two decimals

Tags: sorting, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I want to print floats in a TableView with to decimals. But formatting the floats destroyes the sorting of the column.

```
    TableColumn<Model, String> profit = new TableColumn<Model, String>("Profit");
    profit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Model, String>("profit"));
    profit.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.format("%.2f", cellData.getValue().getProfit()));
```

[image]

If i dont formatting the column the sorting is correct. But the Table shows not two decimals every time.

```
    TableColumn<Model, Float> profit = new TableColumn<Model, Float>("Profit");
    profit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Model, Float>("profit"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use a cell *value* factory to determine what data the cells display, and use a cell factory to determine how the cells should display those data:

```
TableColumn<Model, Float> profit = new TableColumn<Model, Float>("Profit");
profit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Model, Float>("profit"));
profit.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<Model, Float>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Float profit, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(profit, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setText(String.format("%.2f", profit.floatValue()));
        }
    }
});
```